# Qunit is it possible to run tests automatically?

Tags: javascript, qunit

I created several tests in Qunit. Is it possible to run the test automatically ?

Comment: Yes. In what context? Part of a build? Your question is very vague.

Comment: What are the option of the context ? and How I can do it ? Part of the build it also an option

Comment: Your options include a choice between in the client or on the server, part of a build or not, on a chron job or hand-started, and many more...
I would suggest adding more information about your current or desired development setup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tests = [
        { page: "Page01.htm", title: "Test Page 01 - click me to view test page" },
        { page: "Page02.htm" },
        { page: "Page01.htm" }
    ];
    var seq = true; // false to run tests simultaneously
    var runerDne = function(failures, total) {
        // get notified when runner completes
    }
    QUnit.run(tests, seq, runerDne);
```

This loads 3 pages automatically and executes accordingly. Hope this helps you.

Comment: The latest version of QUnit no longer supports the "run()" function.  At one point in time there was a QUnit plugin "composite" that offered similar functionality.  That plugin is no longer in GitHub.